# Ember synchronous looping with service

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, synchronization

How to achieve synchronous loop ? 
I am looping through an array having `id`s. With the `id` I am fetching records from an API and doing some computations.

What I want is to call a function or execute a piece of code **only after one by one execution will get finish in the loop**.

I have tried following code :

```
let cnt = 0;
let successFrwrd = 0;
let failReqFrwrd = 0;
let failRecapFrwrd = 0;
this.checkedItems.forEach((item) => {   
    self.get('store').query('instances', {
        filter : {
            id : item.get('id')
        }
    }).then(instances => {
        if (!instances.get('length')){
            throw new Error();
        }
        if (instances.get('status')===2){
            failReqFrwrd++;
            throw new Error();
        }
        if (instances.get('status')===4){
            failRecapFrwrd++;
            throw new Error();
        }
        return instances.save();
    }).then( () => {
        successFrwrd++;
    }).catch(() => {
        return null;
    });
    cnt++;
    if(cnt === this.checkedItems.length){
        if(successFrwrd > 0){
            console.log(successFrwrd+' Completed' );
        }
        if(failRecapFrwrd >0){
            console.log(failRecapFrwrd+' Recap Fails' );
        }
        if(failReqFrwrd>0){
            console.log(failReqFrwrd+' Request fails' );
        }
    }
});
```

But every time I am getting all counter value as ZERO. There might be more fail reasons i need to display.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, `forEach` does not wait for your promises. Use `reduce` for this. See [this sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3a44f0919b17ce35f16d644d59093436?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).

Also, be carefull about promise chaining: You shouldn't break promise chain. Always return correct promise from inner function. It seems you are not returning a promise from the function.